# ValueError: time data '2017-02-22' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i'm getting **ValueError: time data '2017-02-22' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y** this error
for the below code.

if code is null date format looks like this '22-02-2017' else it looks like this in format '2017-02-22'

previously i used to have null data in code column, but now i don't have.

so i'm using below code to make changes .

```
x1['my_date']=np.where(x1['code'].isnull(),pd.to_datetime(x1['my_date'],format="%d-%m-
%Y"),x1['my_date'])
```

not able to figure out what's wrong with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution add `errors='coerce'` for working if no match (then is returned `NaT`):

```
x1['my_date']=np.where(x1['code'].isnull(),
                       pd.to_datetime(x1['my_date'],format="%d-%m-%Y", errors='coerce'),
                       x1['my_date'])
```

Comment: if code is null (NA's) my_date looks in this format "%d-%m-%Y"  so i'm converting into this "%Y-%m-%d". format where ever code having NA's. no it didn't work